# Returning and Abstract Class?

Tags: java

I have an Abstract class that is like:

```
public abstract class myClass{    

    public abstract double methodOne();
    // returns the data member value for standard deviation

    public abstract double methodTwo(String myString, int myInt);
    // returns the data member value for mean percentage

}
```

Then I have a class which extends this:

```
public class Abstract extends myClass{

    public double methodOne() {
        return 0.00;
    }

    public double methodTwo(String myString, int myInt) {
        return 20.00;   
    }    
}
```

Then finally I have a normal method that's return type is myClass.

```
public myClass anotherMethodOfMine(String myString, int myInt){

}
```

A simple question really, I just don't understand how a method can return another class that itself contains methods? Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: It returns an instance of a class, same as if it was returning a string--another type that has methods.

Comment: Have you ever returned a String? A String contains methods. Have you ever returned an ArrayList? An ArrayList contains methods. Have you ever returned a ____? A ____ contains methods. I frankly don't get the question. Care to go into more detail? Is it simply the *abstract* modifier on the super class that's giving you the trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method returns an object of `MyClass` on which you can call the methods defined there.

You should understand that a class is just a definition of behaviour and data. An object is the actual entity that can perform things with data and can invoke the behaviours defined in the class.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. I've been doing java for a while and never done this but its really quite basic, a gap in my knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

Even though your `myClass` can not be instantiated directly (because it's an abstract class) `Abstract` is a subclass of `myClass` ; this means it has a [is a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is_a) relationship.

Because of this, `Abstract` "is a" `myClass` and it can be returned as an instantiation of the parent class (`myClass`).

Answer (score 0):

Your Method `anotherMethodOfMine(String myString, int myInt)` which will inturn have a object instantiated and returned to the calling function. where you can access the myclass object and use the methods which are defined in the myclass.